# Berks install using artifactory as chef supermarket json parse errors

Tags: chef-infra, artifactory, berkshelf

artifactory_version: 5.8.3
Chef Development Kit Version: 2.4.17
chef-client version: 13.6.4
berks version: 6.3.1
Artifactory is behind a F5 loadbalancer.

When I do berks install and its trying to pull for the artifactory supermarket i'm getting the following error:
ridley-5.1.1/lib/ridley/middleware/parse_json.rb:89:in `first_char': undefined method`[]' for # (NoMethodError)

If I point to supermarket.chef.io it works without any issues.  The local artifactory is a remote repo that proxies supermarket.chef.io and the json files are getting pulling into artifactory.  I've downloaded a couple of them and ran them through a parser and they were good.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What does your berksfile look like?

Comment: # frozen_string_literal: true
source "https://<ARTIFACTORY_SERVER_NAME>/artifactory/api/chef/virt-supermarket"
#source 'https://supermarket.chef.io'
metadata

Comment: Does your repo require authentication? Try `source artifactory: 'https://<ARTIFACTORY_SERVER_NAME>/artifactory/api/chef/virt‌​-supermarket'` instead.

Comment: no auth to just download from artifactory. I did try `source artifctory: 'https://<ARTIFACTORY_SERVER_NAME>/artifactory/api/chef/virt‌​-supermarket'`

Comment: Try the actual artifactory driver anyway just for kicks.

Comment: but still no luck.  same issue of parse_json.rb

Comment: If you manually access `https://<ARTIFACTORY_SERVER_NAME>/artifactory/api/chef/virt‌​‌​-supermarket/universe`, is it well formed JSON?

Comment: Yes it looks like well formed JSON.

Comment: Pastebin the full JSON and the full error stack trace.

Comment: berks install debug output https://pastebin.com/eYMk5yNb

Comment: full JSON is still pasting into a file so can protect the innocent ;)

Comment: JSON file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/q6snl03791nbjhw/universe.json?dl=0

Answer (score 1):

Aha, with the full trace you can see that you aren't using ChefDK's version of things (see the `.rvm` and `ruby-2.5.0` in the paths). Please uninstall everything installed via RVM and use the actual ChefDK packaged versions. This looks like a Ruby 2.5 compat issue, which we haven't tried upgrading to, that will happen in April.